# Phonegap 3.5.0 Cordova File API Error: cannot read property 'dataDirectory' of undefined

Tags: android, ios, file, cordova

We have to build an application for iOS and Android using PhoneGap Build and Apache Cordova.
The Phonegap version is 3.5.0. and we want to update the application when an internet connection is available. So we need to download some images files from online server to local file system into the application(iOS and Android).
Here is the example JavaScript code used:

```
try{
    //The directory to store data
    var store;
    //Used for status updates
    var $status;
    //URL of our asset
    var assetURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/master/readme.md";
    //File name of our important data file we didn't ship with the app
    var fileName = "mydatafile.txt";
    //////////////////////
    alert("Checking for data file.");   
    //Check for the file. 
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
    /////////////////////////////
} catch(e){
    alert(e.message);
}

function downloadAsset() {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    alert("About to start transfer");
    fileTransfer.download(assetURL, store + fileName, 
        function(entry) {
            alert("Success!");
            appStart();
        }, 
        function(err) {
            alert("Error!");
            console.dir(err);
            alert(err);
        });
}

//I'm only called when the file exists or has been downloaded.
function appStart() {
    // $status.innerHTML = "App ready!";
    alert( "App ready!");
}

function onFileSystemSuccess() {
    try{
        store = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
        //Check for the file. 
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(store + fileName, appStart, downloadAsset);
    } catch(e){
        alert(e.message);
    }
}

function onError(){
    alert('error');
}
```

When launching the application, the result is 2 alerts:

- Cannot read property 'dataDirectory' of *undefined* `// alert(e.message);`
- Error `// alert('Error');`

Comment: Is the `window.requestFileSystem` executed after _deviceReady_ is fired?

Comment: Yes, it's executed after deviceready event is fired.

Comment: And you have the file plugin correctly installed for that platform? Are you possibly using PhoneGap Build, or just plain Cordova CLI?

Comment: The File plugin is used from the config.xml file for Phonegap Build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we found the problem!
Inside the app, we have included the cordova js file using the downloaded version of cordova plugin, which included in the `js` folder of the app.
So instead of the below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
```

it's recommended to type:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And Phongap will add the cordova file itself.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound stupid but for all sort of "cannot read property" issues, you may also try

`rm -rf plugins`
`cordova/ionic platform remove xxx`
`cordova/ionic platform add xxx`

It solved my problem which doesn't really make sense at all. Who would expect the plugins themselves are getting wrong?

Comment: The plugins , sometimes, would having a bugs which needed to be fixed, this issue happens in many environment...